# Problems with PDF output and TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm working with Fabrik and TCPDF in order to create a PDF of an existing form through "PHP form plugin" and then send it via email with the "email form plugin", from Fabrik both two plugins. This PDF contains placeholders and images, and as I said it's a custom PDF with the submitted record's detail view from the form page I want to send.
The problem is that there's no way to output this PDF with PHP form plugin to a specific path (in fact, code just doesn't create the PDF if you force it to do it). Another problem I have it's that signature doesn't appear in my PDF even though I linked it well.

I've tried attaching an already existing PDF, and it works perfectly (so I imagine that the problem is with "PHP form plugin"). I've tried creating and attaching a PDF with a hardcoded name (without placeholders), and it doesn't work.

Here is what I've written on email plugin "attachments eval" (which I think it's fine, doesn't need modification):

```php
<?php
$form[] = '/authorizations/{tablename___elementname}.pdf';
  return $form;
?>
```

Here you have the problematic line of the last PHP code I've used on PHP form plugin:

```php
$pdf->Output(JPATH_ROOT . '/authorizations' . '/' . '{tablename___elementname}.pdf', 'F');
```

I've also tried this:

```php
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '{tablename___elementname}.pdf', 'F');
```

This code from above creates the PDF, but I can't attach it with the email form plugin even though I know its full path. The same happens with the one from below:

```php
$pdf->Output('{tablename___elementname}.pdf', 'F');
```

The most annoying error that has been present throughout my journey is: *TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file*. It appeared as soon as I was trying to go into the page of the form, when I used an URL instead of a full path. But that's not a problem now.

PD: I know that I probably shouldn't, but I'm gonna leave here below the whole PHP code I've written in "PHP form plugin", in case you need it. Some element names change, don't worry ;).

```php
<?php
require_once('libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
  $pdf->SetAuthor('me');
  $pdf->SetTitle('Device authorization: {tablename___device}');
  $pdf->SetSubject('authorization');
  $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' {tablename___device}', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
  $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));
  $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
  $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
  $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
  $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
  $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12, '', true);
  $pdf->AddPage();
$html = <<<EOD
<p>Text</p>
<p> </p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Name</strong></span>: {tablename___name}</p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Surname</strong></span>: {tablename___surname}</p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Devices</strong></span>: {tablename___devices}</p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Signature (using digsig)</strong></span>: <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_fabrik\&amp;task=plugin.pluginAjax\&amp;plugin=digsig\&amp;method=ajax_signature_to_image\&amp;format=raw\&amp;element_id=35\&amp;formid=5\&amp;rowid={tablename___id}\&amp;repeatcount=0" alt="" width="400" height="250" /></p>
<p> </p>
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->Output(JPATH_ROOT . '/authorizations' . '/' . '{tablename___device}.pdf', 'F');
?>
```

Comment: Does `is_writeable(JPATH_ROOT . '/authorizations');` return true? 

Basically, first thing I'd check is "does my target directory exist and is it writeable by the script?", especially if it works with `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, but not my desired target.

Comment: So you think it's a permission issue? Then I could talk with my hosting and solve the problem from there, isn't that true?

Comment: It's possible. I'd check with `is_writeable` first. Also should probably double-check that `JPATH_ROOT` is what you're expecting.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll keep you posted.